# Using Semaphores to ensure order

Tags: semaphore, pseudocode

Suppose that there is a game where three players move, and each player is given a color (R,G,B). Is there a way to ensure that the players move in the order R then G then B using only semaphores, if three routines must be made (one for each player's move)? (Assuming that R will always start).

This question is not supposed to take into account any special type of semaphores that might be found in a particular programming language, instead it should just be a textbook semaphore.

My proposed solution was (in pseudo code):

```
Red {
     wait(R)
     wait(B)
     wait(G)
          Move Red
     signal(G)
     signal(B)
     signal(R)
}

Blue {
     wait(R)
     wait(B)
     wait(G)
          Move Blue
     signal(G)
     signal(B)
     signal(R)
}

Green {
     wait(R)
     wait(B)
     wait(G)
          Move Green
     signal(G)
     signal(B)
     signal(R)
}
```

But I don't think this works because while Red is guaranteed to go first, then we don't know that Blue is going to get the B semaphore before Green gets it; or even that Blue will get the R semaphore before Green gets it.

Is there another way to do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your code, the fact that all three 'tasks' (Red, Green, and Blue) all have the same structure is a danger sign that something might be wrong.

Consider the 2 color case first - it might help you think about the problem.

If we want just want red to go before blue, we can write

```
Red 
{
   Move Red
   signal(R)
   wait(B)
}

Blue
{
   wait(R)
   Move Blue
   signal(B)
}
```

If we want the 3 color case, we can extend that

```
Red 
{
   Move Red
   signal(R)
   wait(B)

}

Green
{
   wait(R)
   Move Green
   signal(G)
}

Blue
{
   wait(G)
   Move Blue
   signal(B)
}
```

The Red player doesn't have to wait until after he's moved. After he moves, he signals that he's moved and waits for Blue's signal.

The Green player initially waits for Red's signal. When he gets it, he moves and then signals. When we next enter the Green 'function', he will wait for Red's signal again.

The Blue player does the same thing as the Green player, except he's waiting on Green's signal instead of Red's.

You can see that this can be generalized for any positive integer number of colors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with a circular signaling.
For a starting the game you need to signal the Player 1 directly.
Then sequence would follow as:
- Wait on red. Move red. Signal blue.
- Wait on blue. Move blue. Signal green.
- Wait on green. Move green. Signal red.